# Shrink floated div with its container and prevent it from wrapping to next line

Tags: html, css

I have two floated divs, the one on the left has a set width, the other does not. What I'm trying to figure out is a way to prevent them from stacking on top of one another as their container shrinks, but to instead have the second one shrink with the container.

```
<style>
.row {
   float:left;
}
.cell {
    float: left;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="cell" style="width:50px">a</div>
    <div class="cell">b</div>
</div>
```

So in this example, I need b to shrink dynamically without wrapping to the next line.

Comment: The problem isn't `b`, it is that `a` has a fixed width. if the window is 50px wide, where do you expect `b` to go?

Comment: You mean, shrink the text?

Comment: @Rhumborl Wouldn't a minimum width on the row set larger than 50px solve that?

Comment: @chiapa, Yes, there would be text within the second div, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4oga5mha/1/)

```css
.row {
   float:left;
   width: 100%;
}

.cell {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;        
}

#right-cell {
    float: initial
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell" style="width: 50px">a</div>
    <div class="cell" id="right-cell">sdfsd fsd sdf sd fsdf sdf dsfdsf dsf sdb sdfsd fsd sdf sd fsdf sdf dsfdsf dsf sdb sdfsd fsd sdf sd fsdf sdf dsfdsf dsf sdb sdfsd fsd sdf sd fsdf sdf dsfdsf dsf sdb sdfsd fsd sdf sd fsdf sdf dsfdsf dsf sdb sdfsd fsd sdf sd fsdf sdf dsfdsf dsf sdb</div>
</div>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I want, just having trouble implementing it into my actual page. Isn't behaving the same way for some reason.

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk, glad I could help! Got it working already? Which browser are you working with? Try to put `float: none` instead of `float: initial`, that may be the issue

Comment: Yup! I'm not really sure what the problem was to be honest. I think Chrome may have just been bugging out on me or something. Can't believe I hadn't thought to just take float off the second element. So simple. Thanks for the help!